# Что является best-practice'ом интернационализации flash'ей?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, i18n

На Rails Guides написано следующее:

> For example, your config/locales directory could look like this:

```
|-defaults  
|---es.rb  
|---en.rb  
|-models  
|---book  
|-----es.rb  
|-----en.rb  
|-views  
|---defaults  
|-----es.rb  
|-----en.rb  
|---books  
|-----es.rb  
|-----en.rb  
|---users  
|-----es.rb  
|-----en.rb  
|---navigation  
|-----es.rb  
|-----en.rb
```

> This way, you can separate model and model attribute names from text
>   inside views, and all of this from the "defaults" (e.g. date and time
>   formats). Other stores for the i18n library could provide different
>   means of such separation.

Но здесь ничего не сказано про то, как хранить файлы переводов flash сообщений (они ведь находятся в контроллерах, а здесь даже папки такой нет).

Отсюда вопрос: как правильно организовать хранение переводов flash сообщений? В переводах для представлений хранить нет смысла, ибо один и тот же flash может появляться на разных страницах. Может стоит хранить их в папке defaults? Но я не считаю это самым рациональным решением, ведь flash'ы сами по себе не являются чем-то "дефолтным". Может быть стоит сделать отдельную папку controllers и хранить в ней? Но тогда какова должна быть структура самого файла?

Что-то типа этого?

```
en:
  activecontroller:
    users:
      ...
```

И вообще, найдут ли тогда рельсы эти файлы, если обратиться в контроллере как `t('.myflash)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно делать в `config/locales` что угодно, в целом. Нету папок? Добавьте!  Раскидывать переводы по отдельным файлам можете как вам будет удобнее.

Флэш-сообщения хранить в отдельных файлах смысла мало. То, что они задаются в контроллере, это скорее техническая деталь, в конечном счёте они всё равно отображаются в представлениях. Но если вы считаете, что так будет удобнее — сделайте отдельно.

Какой ключ будут искать рельсы, можно очень просто проверить, сделав в экшене `binding.pry` (с гемом `pry`, конечно) и попросив заведомо несуществующий перевод:

```
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-05-18 17:34:22 +0300
Processing by HomeController#index as HTML

From: %project%/app/controllers/home_controller.rb @ line 4 HomeController#index:

    2: def index
    3:   binding.pry
 => 4:   render json: {success: true, arr: [*1..10]}
    5: end

[1] pry(#<HomeController>)> t '.wheehaa'
=> "translation missing: en.home.index.wheehaa"
```

Значит, для этого случая размещать строку придётся примерно так:

```
en:
  home:
    index:
      wheehaa: "Whe-e-eha-a-a!"
```

В каком файле — неважно.

Comment: Спасибо. Еще попутно вопрос задам. Как известно, ошибки валидации переводятся следующим образом: https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/blob/master/rails/locale/be.yml (строка 108). А что делать в том случае, если ты сам добавляешь ошибку? Например так:  
`@user.errors.add :current_password, "is incorrect"`.

Comment: @МатвейМамонов [в исходниках Rails](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activemodel/lib/active_model/validations/numericality.rb) закидывают символ.

Comment: Извините за мою безграмотность, но я не совсем понял, что вы имеете в виду. Нужно добавлять ошибки так: `@user.errors.add :current_password, :is_invalid`?

Comment: @МатвейМамонов Если верить исходникам по ссылке, то да.

Comment: Ну исходникам, думаю, всегда стоит верить. Что ж, спасибо, что помогли разобраться, а то я бы сам до этого не додумался.